# Navigating a large ruby codebase, like rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been a java developer for most of my career, and developed and maintained some pretty large code bases.

now that I've been developing in rails for a while I've left my IDE behind and I want so start looking at the actual rails source. I've mainly been using the github interface which is actually quite good but I wondered if there were tips and techniques from more seasoned ruby devs?

What I'm missing mainly is my trusted eclipse features like "find usage" or "goto implementaton". Perhaps a paradigm shift is in order... please enlighten me :P

Comment: It depends on what your current tool-chain looks like.  What editor have you settled on?  For instance, I use vim and the rails.vim, along with several other vim plugins.  But that's useless to someone who uses Textmate or another editor.

Comment: I haven't used Rubymine, but I expect that in any IDE those "find usage" and "goto implementation" are not going to work so well for Ruby because of the dynamic way that methods are defined and redefined.  I usually just use recursive `grep` to search for the name of the function in my all ruby files.

Comment: I would go with @DavidGrayson suggestion and vim/TextMate as editor

Comment: I've settled on Vim and sublime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're an Eclipse user I'd recommend [Rubymine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/). It gives you a lot of the same features and has good integration with rails. It has good support for jumping to implementation/usage, although this is a harder problem in ruby than java. When Rubymine can't determine which implementation is the correct one, you're usually given a list of all matching methods.

I personally use Vi and haven't had trouble navigating rails projects, usually it's a matter of convention and familiarity that just comes with working on the same project for enough time. I default to using grep or find for usages etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that things like "goto implementation" and its ilk may require deep knowledge of the runtime. Some methods may not exist until after an initialization or mixin process. Duck typing means that anything that responds to a message is a potential type candidate.

I'm reasonably happy with IntelliJ (Rubymine), but you won't find the same level of navigational support you get from a language like Java, where most everything is known up front. It's simply less navigable than Java code, IMO.

The things that *can* be known, like explicitly-defined methods, "obvious" calls, and so on *are* navigable, and IMO right now IntelliJ does it the best, but I haven't used an Eclipse Ruby environment for some time, so the situation may be different now--but I'm often surprised at how well it *does* do, considering the circumstances.

That said, I flip back-and-forth between IntelliJ, TextMate, Sublime Text 2, and Emacs. TextMate is nearly useless to me because of its single-pane design. For quick stuff or small projects, it's adequate.